# Does cell phone radiation promote longevity?

Tags: cancer, experimental-design, radiation

[This preprint](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2016/06/23/055699) presents results from a 2-year National Toxicology Program study on the effects of cell-phone radiation in rats. On page 8 of the PDF, survival results are presented. The presentation of the results is complicated by the fact that some treatment groups experienced significantly different effects when compared to the control group, while in other groups the effect was small but not significant. However, the gist is that rats treated with phone radiation lived longer, and that the effect is stronger in male rats.

I was confused by the fact that this result is presented in the "Results" section on page 8, while the seemingly less significant finding - that treated rats had higher rates of cancer or tumors - was presented in the "Summary" section on page 4. Obviously the study was funded to address concerns we have about observed relationships between cell-phone use and cancer, but when an effect on longevity was discovered, shouldn't this have become the primary result?

The plots on page 11 (Figure 3) and 12 (Figure 4) show some more interesting relationships between the survival of the various groups. Figure 4A shows the high-dose (6W/kg) CDMA male group overtaking the control males only towards the end of the study. With the GSM males (Figure 3A), as well as the low-dose CDMA males, the control group does worse almost from the beginning.

I'm curious to know why more people haven't commented on this result in news outlets. My opinion is that controlled experiments in animals aren't perfect, but they're much better than cheap "longitudinal" studies in humans. As far as I can tell, this is the best evidence we have to date, and it says that cell phone radiation promotes longevity. So why aren't we being required to sleep with phones next to our heads?

Comment: I don't think it is useful or relevant to discuss preprints. Wait until they have appeared in peer-reviewed journals.

Comment: @David There are actually a bunch of reviews at the end of that document. Most take (quite negative) issue with the study design and power.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the discussion, and also the full contents of the PDF which include some reviewer comments, there is concern about the control group:

> The survival of the control group of male rats in the current study (28%) was relatively low
>   compared to other recent NTP studies in Hsd:Sprague Dawley® SD® (Harlan) rats (average 47%, range 24-72%).

Specifically, the control group had an abnormally high mortality rate for that strain of rat. There is no increase in longevity if you compare to historical data.

Comment: Yes, I read that. Is your argument that we should (a) do away with control groups and just compare with non-randomized controls from historical rat populations used in different studies in other parts of the world? Or that we should (b) use control groups but ignore the results when we disagree with them, falling back on historical statistics?

Comment: Because a randomized trial gives us a p-value, which, although not reported by the authors of this study, tells us that the in case of the null hypothesis, where the treatment is not doing anything, the observed differences between groups must indicate that a e.g. 1 in 20, or a 1 in 1000, event happened. And I thought the point of statistical analysis was not to fall back on explaining our results as due to extreme randomness.

Comment: @Metamorphic No, a control group should still definitely be used. p-values don't prove truth, they tell you when your results are more different than you would expect if there is no real effect, with some reasonable margin for error built in. You always have to use other sources of information at hand to interpret your results. It would already be a little extreme to change behavior based on just one study, and even more extreme to change behavior based on a study where there seems to be a significant problem with the control group.

Comment: @Metamorphic Not to mention the study also showed more tumors in the test groups than the control group, though that is also suspect because of the short lifespan of the controls. Truthfully, it seems like whether by randomness or some unknown factor not accounted for in the study, this work will have to be repeated with a new set of subjects to provide a result that can inspire more confidence.

Comment: I admit that the idea of changing behavior was a bit tongue-in-cheek - although for many people this would not be a change of behavior. But I'm not sure we're on the same page with the results - why do you say there is a "significant problem with the control group"? What would make it different from the other groups? They were all treated identically, except for radiation levels. Further, your quote indicates that the control group survival was not outside of the range of normal survival rates, so your use of the adjective "significant" seems misleading given the context.

Comment: Well, they gave a full range, not an interquartile range, and I am assuming they are basing that on many studies. It could be that only 1 study out of 1000 had lower survival than this one. It was sufficiently significant for both the authors and the reviewers to comment on it being an issue with the study. As far as the control group, we don't know precisely how the control group was treated. The researchers no doubt tried to treat the control group equally, but maybe they did not. Maybe control animal cages were in a row and disease spread between them when they were handled.

Comment: ...the point is, we don't really know, but the control group is enough of an outlier from other studies that we should think more carefully about the results. You are much more likely to make a type 1 error if the control group itself is in the lower end of normal, and in fact this sort of thing happens all the time, especially if you consider a p-value of 0.05 to be significant. Part of your question was asking why this study isn't getting more play and why the authors didn't focus on this point: I think it's because they are not confident it is a real result, and they expressed that concern.

Comment: Thank you for thinking about this. I think that what it boils down to is, the authors don't give us enough data to make sense of their results. This is somewhat frustrating and makes me wonder what is being covered up - whether it is experimenter incompetence, as if the control group rats were all "in a row" as you say; or, alternatively, if it is a result which might threaten their National Toxicology Program funding, such as "X is not toxic".

Comment: @Metamorphic don't look for conspiracy where there likely is none. I personally applaud the researchers for publishing mixed results - that's not done often enough, and skews the literature (and our understanding) to a potentially large degree. Not every study will give perfect, absolutely clear-cut results. We don't know a lot of things, but that doesn't mean they're being covered up intentionally. Maybe it was a poorly-trained grad student. Maybe it was disease, or the animal facility staff, or the facility itself, or the supplier, or a million other possibilities. Don't be paranoid.

Comment: @MattDMo: "Don't look for a conspiracy"? "Don't be paranoid?" I don't appreciate your patronizing generalizations. Everyone has bias and you know very well that we can discuss that here. If you're so interested to distinguish between bias and incompetence, don't write to me. Write to the authors and ask for their p-values. Maybe you'll have better luck than I did.

I don't even know why you would bring up conspiracies in this case. The bigger "conspiracy" would be if they had bias in the other direction.

Comment: @Metamorphic I don't think MattDMo meant any harm. You are coming here and saying "Why aren't people taking this study more seriously?" and we are giving you a very good reason: because the data are suspect. That doesn't mean you throw out the results. I don't think the researchers are incompetent, as you suggest, I think they are pragmatic and reasonable: something in their results looks funny, so they aren't putting much stock in it until it gets confirmed. That's responsible research. I also wouldn't say the NTP's funding is dependent on finding particular things toxic.

Comment: @MattDMo makes a great point as well about the skew in the literature: that many studies go unpublished when the results are suspect or borderline. That's actually a big problem. It's much better to publish the results, with the appropriate caveats noted, so that future studies can take it into consideration. If you zap two more studies worth of rodents with cell phone radiation and their control groups suffer again, we can start to conclude that the radiation is making telekinetic rats that suck the life force out of their kin to prolong their lives. Until then, let's be cautious.

Comment: @Bryan: If you or Matt write asking for p-values and quantiles, that would be great. They exist, and at this point getting them *should* be easier than theorizing about our beliefs about other people's beliefs. ... Until then, I like your last hypothesis :)

Comment: @Metamorphic The paper hasn't even completed the peer-review process; the reviews included in the pdf you linked have already asked for some additional statistical presentation of the results, including p-values. I suspect all of these will be in the final publication.

Comment: @Bryan: I think that the pre-print phase is a great time to correspond with the authors of a paper. If you want to wait, that's fine. Just remember that the purpose of getting those numbers is primarily to validate the assumption in your answer, that certain deviations were significant. My question is based on significances already validated by the reviewers (e.g. p. 53). You could also replicate what the authors did by tracking down recent NTP SD-rat studies. Then collate the control group survival rates, and run a t-test. If you get say p < 0.05 then I would accept your answer.

Comment: @Metamorphic Did you read the entirety of the PDF you linked in your original question? NIH reviewers have already raised these issues, and uniformly show concern about the survival rates. Page 53 and similar was simply checking that the statistical calculations were performed correctly, and says nothing about the reviewers opinions of the data themselves, which they clearly feel are suspect.

Comment: @Bryan: I'm not interested in counting the number of reviewers that expressed concern, what's more interesting, for your argument, is counting the number of rats that survived and relating it to other studies. Is the relationship statistically significant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51638/discussion-between-bryan-krause-and-metamorphic).

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm curious to know why more people haven't commented on this result
>   in news outlets"

Because for once the news outlets appear to be behaving responsibly, and waiting until the results are published in a peer-reviewed journal. You could do worse than follow their example.

Comment: @AliceD — I am sorry but it answers the part of the question I quoted. It is not a request for clarification nor a critique (in the correct or incorrect usage of the word), and it is in no sense suitable for a comment. In any case this is an old question that has only resurfaced because someone has dug it up. Not worth a flame war now.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious to know why more people haven't commented on this result
>   in news outlets.

This is an easy point: nobody is interested in publishing this. A quick scan of my (not that bad) local newspaper shows stories in a few categories:

- Photogenic stuff. About the moon, Antarctica, animals etc.
- Male/female stuff, why we are not the same, or why women are better at something
- Everything about food, medicine and vitamins
- Climate change

Besides that, the story has to be news. It has to have some actuality, fit in with previous/further stories people are talking about, and people have to want to read it.

This story has none of that. Nobody is talking about cell phone radiation, and people are already convinced that it's not dangerous. 15 years ago this would definitely be on science pages everywhere.

Then there's also the science. Apart from what people are saying in the comments, you just cherry picked a single data point from a single study. The study was not designed and powered to show that cell phones increase survival, the authors don't focus on it (rightfully so), and there's also no plausible mechanism how this should work.

You can have a theoretical discussion about whether or not this fact is a reliable fact, and about whether or not the authors did everything right. However, I would put all my money on future research showing no enhanced survival, because circumstantial evidence is pointing in that direction and there's no mechanism.

Comment: Good first half, but... "you just cherry picked a single data point from a single study" - What are the other studies? I mean, other studies that would provide evidence about survival effects. "The study was not designed and powered to show that cell phones increase survival" - not designed in what way? "circumstantial evidence is pointing in that direction" - good if true, but can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: It's highly likely there are other studies where animals are exposed to cell phone radiation. Probably there this effect is absent or not significant. Not designed / powered: if there is an effect it's likely that it's (extremely) small. By doing the study with low power, you're very likely to get either nothing (expected) or, if you get a statistically significant effect, the effect size will be overestimated. The circumstantial evidence is that similar mice in identical control groups that usually live longer.

Comment: See #3 in my question. If you think another study is relevant, I need you to track down the citation. Otherwise you're asking anyone who disagrees with you to cite every study ever published and show that it doesn't meet your advertised criteria. Some estimate that a total of 50 million journal articles have been published to date. It's much easier if you just tell us where to look.

Comment: You were interested enough to look this up in the first place, why would you stop looking when you find one number that fits what you want to think?

Comment: I don't appreciate your condescension. I made a simple request. Please back up your claims, or don't participate here.

Comment: @Metamorphic VonBeche is not condescending you. Every single person who has answered or commented here has roughly the same opinion. You are here asking for our help - no one is being paid here to do work for you. Sometimes it's helpful to teach by giving the answers, but more often its best to give someone the tools to do their own work on the subject.

Comment: I don't have time to play your games @Bryan. This page is for people who want to answer my question. If you think it would be a waste of your time to do that, or if you think that you would be hindering me from "getting tools", then either way you don't belong here. It's a Q&A site.

Comment: Your question wasn't about the dangers cell phone radiation, it was about why nobody was talking about this research and why the WHO doesn't advice us to sleep with our phones. The answer to that is just that it's not interesting and that the result is probably wrong. If you want to know more about this field of research I can recommend you to read some more literature and look up some reviews. To refer to the guidelines: "some thorough searching for the answer is expected". You came here with one cherry picked data point.